# Adding existing site column to the SharePoint list using PowerShell client side

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-list

I am trying to add an existing site column to the SharePoint list. I have tried the following code:

```
#Setup the context
$listTitle = "VersionCleanup2247"
$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)
$clientContext.Load($clientContext.Web);
$clientContext.Load($clientContext.Web.Lists);
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

$list = $clientContext.Web.lists | where{$_.Title -eq $listTitle}

if($list)
{
    Write-Host "list is already there. Loading the existing list."
    $list = $clientContext.Web.lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)
    $clientContext.Load($list);
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host "Loaded" -ForegroundColor Green
}
Write-Host "Loading the default view of list"
$defaultView = $list.defaultView
$clientContext.Load($defaultView)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
Write-Host "Loaded" -ForegroundColor Green

Write-Host "Loading the available field in the current site"
$siteColumns = $clientContext.Web.Fields
$clientContext.Load($siteColumns)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
Write-Host "Loaded" -ForegroundColor Green

Write-host "adding comments fields from available site columns to the list"
$colName = $siteColumns | Where {$_.InternalName -eq "_Comments"}
$clientContext.Load($colName)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
$list.Fields.Add($colName)
$list.Update()
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

$defaultView.ViewFields.Add("Comments")
$defaultView.Update()
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Here I am trying to add a column whose internal name is `_Comments`and Display name is `Comments`. But while adding it I am getting the following error:

> Error info! Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Field or property "DescriptionResource" does not exist."

Following dll files I am loading:

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "c:\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
```

And I have the full admin access on the site. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: ..could have something to do with the version of Sharepoint you are targetting.. Are you referencing the correct Microsoft.SharePoint.Client dll version(s)?

Comment: I got the same error message while performing a different operation: to delete a Site Action. The solution turns out to be use $objectArray.Item(0) to retrieve the item you about to delete instead of using $objectArray[0]. Hope this could be helpful.